# What are Interface principals?

Tags: oop, interface

I went for interview and suddenly i was asked:

> **What are interface principals?**

Which made me strange because from OOP point of view we know that:

> interface separates the implementation and defines the structure

I dont know if ever i missed telling design principal i.e S.O.L.I.D which can relates interface principal. Where:

```
S – Single-responsiblity principle
O – Open-closed principle
L – Liskov substitution principle
I – Interface segregation principle
D – Dependency Inversion Principle
```

link: https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design

So is S.O.L.I.D is interface principals?

Comment: SOLID is just best practices and can be applied both to interfaces and classes

Comment: so SOLID is not a interface principles?

Comment: I've not heard about *interface principles* anything

Comment: The I in SOLID -- Interface Segregation Principle might have been what they were hinting at.

Comment: Some interviewers check your confidence level by asking slightly odd questions. A person who is quite confident about OOP, SOLID and Interface, will ask more questions to clarify what interviewer mean by 'Interface Principle'.

Answer (score 0):

The main principles of an Interface is

- Interfaces model similar capabilities of classes that might otherwise be
  very different
- Interfaces models “act as” relationships while inheritance models “is a”
- Interface acts as a contract that Java must enforce

Comment: OK thanks. very much informative. Can i also say Interface acts as a contract for C#?